# FFMPEG how to use functions from libswscale when writing filter for libavfilter

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to write some filters for FFMPEG and I would like to use some already created filters for preprocessing planes. How can one do that? I have a standard loop for plane processing:

```
int p;
    if (av_frame_is_writable(in)) {
        out = in;
    } else {
        out = ff_get_video_buffer(outlink, outlink->w, outlink->h);
        if (!out) {
            av_frame_free(&in);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        av_frame_copy_props(out, in);
    }
    // processing planes
    for (p = 0; p < filter->nb_planes; p++) {
        pad_plane();
        transpose_plane(); // etc...  
        apply_my_filter();          
    }

    if (out != in)
        av_frame_free(&in);
    return ff_filter_frame(outlink, out);
```

I do believe padding and transposing is already possible in FFMPEG's other libraries. What is a common way to do it so I would be able to use them inside mine filter code?

Comment: Take a look at the source for [zoompan](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_zoompan.c) filter.

Comment: Thank you @Mulvya. It is always hard to find a filter from which would demonstrate the use of some features. This one seems to be quite explanatory.